# Xamarin.Ios crash when AddContact is called

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin.IOS application and I try to write a new contact. For that I followed this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/contacts/#contacts

But When I hit the following line:

```
saveRequest.AddContact(contact, store.DefaultContainerIdentifier);
```

The App Crashes with the following output logged:

```
2017-07-21 18:25:16.912 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    0   ConnectContacts.Ios                 0x0000000104b72501 mono_handle_native_crash + 257
2017-07-21 18:25:16.912 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000110971b3a _sigtramp + 26
2017-07-21 18:25:16.912 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    2   ???                                 0x0000000105132c2a 0x0 + 4380109866
2017-07-21 18:25:16.912 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000011087434f fcntl + 0
2017-07-21 18:25:16.913 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    4   TCC                                 0x00000001120bb6d5 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80 + 0
2017-07-21 18:25:16.913 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    5   TCC                                 0x00000001120bb61f __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 0
2017-07-21 18:25:16.913 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    6   TCC                                 0x00000001120be56d __tccd_send_block_invoke + 305
2017-07-21 18:25:16.913 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    7   libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001108185ba _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 45
2017-07-21 18:25:16.913 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    8   libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001108102cb _xpc_connection_call_reply + 36
2017-07-21 18:25:16.913 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110521792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
2017-07-21 18:25:16.914 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110507eb6 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 763
2017-07-21 18:25:16.914 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110509899 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 813
2017-07-21 18:25:16.914 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011050950d _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
2017-07-21 18:25:16.914 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110983616 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
2017-07-21 18:25:16.914 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical:    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001109830f1 start_wqthread + 13
2017-07-21 18:25:16.915 ConnectContacts.Ios[31854:7762750] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runt
ime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
The app has been terminated.
Launch failed. The app 'ConnectContacts.Ios' could not be launched on 'iPhone 7 iOS 10.3'. Error: An error occurred while executing MTouch. Please check the logs for more details.
The app has been terminated.
```

I already tried to catch the error with a try catch. But this is just ignored.

Here is my method:

```
    public void SaveContact()
    {           

        // Create a new Mutable Contact (read/write)
        var contact = new CNMutableContact();

        // Set standard properties
        contact.GivenName = "John";
        contact.FamilyName = "Appleseed";

        // Add email addresses
        var homeEmail = new CNLabeledValue<NSString>(CNLabelKey.Home, new NSString("john.appleseed@mac.com"));
        var workEmail = new CNLabeledValue<NSString>(CNLabelKey.Work, new NSString("john.appleseed@apple.com"));
        contact.EmailAddresses = new CNLabeledValue<NSString>[] { homeEmail, workEmail };

        // Add phone numbers
        var cellPhone = new CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>(CNLabelPhoneNumberKey.iPhone, new CNPhoneNumber("713-555-1212"));
        var workPhone = new CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>("Work", new CNPhoneNumber("408-555-1212"));
        contact.PhoneNumbers = new CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>[] { cellPhone, workPhone };

        // Add work address
        var workAddress = new CNMutablePostalAddress()
        {
            Street = "1 Infinite Loop",
            City = "Cupertino",
            State = "CA",
            PostalCode = "95014"
        };
        contact.PostalAddresses = new CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>[] { new CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>(CNLabelKey.Work, workAddress) };

        // Add birthday
        var birthday = new NSDateComponents()
        {
            Day = 1,
            Month = 4,
            Year = 1984
        };
        contact.Birthday = birthday;

        try
        {
            // Save new contact
            var store = new CNContactStore();
            var saveRequest = new CNSaveRequest();
            saveRequest.AddContact(contact, store.DefaultContainerIdentifier);

            // Attempt to save changes
            NSError error;
            if (store.ExecuteSaveRequest(saveRequest, out error))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New contact saved");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Save error: {0}", error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This get's called in the ViewDidLoad of my MainView:

```
        new AddressBookService().SaveContact();
```

I test on the IPhone Simulator with IOS 10.3.
I added this key to the Entitlement.plist file:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>    
<string>This app request access for your contacts</string>
```

But the request permissions dialog is never shown. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. First i had to put the entries into the info.plist. Second I change the part for saving like this:

```
// Save new contact
        var store = new CNContactStore();
        store.RequestAccess(CNEntityType.Contacts, (granted, nsError) =>
        {
            if (!granted) return;

            var saveRequest = new CNSaveRequest();
            saveRequest.AddContact(contact, store.DefaultContainerIdentifier);

            // Attempt to save changes
            NSError error;
            if (store.ExecuteSaveRequest(saveRequest, out error))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New contact saved");
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Save error: {0}", error);
            }
        });
```

Now the request for permissons pops up properly.